# When I try type="module" get this Error ( Uncaught ReferenceError: loadFoods is not defined)

Tags: javascript

When I use type="application/javascript" everything is okay.

```
<script type="module"  src="./assets/scripts/homepage.js></script>
<script>
   loadFoods()
</script>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Answer (score 2):

Variables inside modules are scoped to those modules.

They aren't designed to create global variables (although there are hacky ways to achieve that).

The `<script>` element should be the **entry point** to the program, not a means to load a dependency. That is what `import` is for.

Your approach should be something more along the lines of:

```
<script type="module">
    import {loadFoods} from "./assets/scripts/homepage.js";
    loadFoods();
</script>
```

Obviously the homepage module needs to explicitly export the `loadFoods` function.